# Winform redirect a button click to numeric up / down

Tags: c#, numericupdown

The numeric up down controls are to smart to be touched on my touch screen.
And so i want to code to push them by a another button (a large button with a up triangle image and another large button with a triangle down).

To get the behviour i made a onclick event on the numeric updowncontrol.

```
    private void nudScanWindowY_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gbNumericUpDown2.Visible = true;
        numericUpdownHelper = 8;
    }
```

Then groupbox with large up / down buttons on it is shown.
and to differentiate between various updown controls a number is given.
By use of a switch commend the right numeric updown was updated

```
     select(numericUpdownHelper)
     case 8:
                if (nudScanWindowY.Value < 400) nudScanWindowY.Value++;
                nudScanWindowY.Show();
                break;
```

This worked for several numeric updowns, but some numeric updowns have more complex logic behind them altering multiple variables.

So now i wonder is there a way with winforms, to do something like this:

```
      btnLargeUP_Click(object sender EventArgs e)
      {
        if(numericUpdownHelper == 8)nudScanWindowY.pressUP()  
      }
```

in such a way that the same code would get executed as by getting that tiny controls up button  ?.

update

I also tried below but in some cases even that doesnt work

```
 case 8:
    nudScanWindowY.Value++;
    nudScanWindowY_ValueChanged(sender,  e);
```

Comment: Why don't you just execute the same code, that would be executed on the numeric up-down button?

Comment: I wouldn't use the numeric up/down when implementing my own up/down buttons. I would probably create a UserControl with a textbox and some buttons. The buttons will try to parse the textbox.Text and increment the result if it was valid. Al this functionality is implemented in the control so this way you can reuse the control anywhere without conficts.

Comment: i normally wouldnt either, but originally it wasnt made to work with a small touch screen. Since the code is large and complex, i begin to think that some pressUP or pressDown emulation would be the least 'disturbing' to code, keeping the original code behaviour intact